# Bad CPU type in executable: '/Users/mac/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver'

Tags: python-3.x

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

urls = ['https://www.techwithtim.net/']
cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='/Users/mac/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver')

for url in urls:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=cService)  
driver.get(url)
```

All above is my code.When i run it, there is wrong in line :driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=cService).It show that :[Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable: '/Users/mac/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver'.

So how could i work out it?
Or if my mac intel core is not matched?

Comment: If your Mac has an Intel processor then this is the wrong driver.  The path of the driver strongly suggests it is for an ARM processor. Which would explain the error you get.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. I changed the right driver as you said way and succeed.